# I have recently install magento 2.3, the app/design/frontend/magento/ is empty

Tags: magento2, frontend, luma-theme, customizable-options

I have recently install Magento 2.3. The `app/design/frontend/magento/`  is empty. I want to modify the product detail page and catalog detail pages. I am new to Magento can anybody help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create a new theme based on Magento luma or blank. please read through Magento Doc:

```
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html
```

You could follow that tutorial to create your own theme (MyCompony/mytheme). And copy all files in (vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/) into your new theme folder (app/design/MyCompony/mytheme/Mage_Catalog/templates/product/). If you want to edit  category page just modify the list.phtml. For Product detail page, you have to modify the corresponding files inside product/view/.

Comment: Thank you for this help.